# how to add checkboxes to stacklayout from model

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a view (xaml) which contains a stacklayout with the id "CheckBoxList". From the viewmodel I would like to add some checkboxes to this stacklayout. But I don't know how. I can't use

```
CheckBoxList.Children.Add(checkbox);
```

Is there a easy way to do that?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "an easy way"? Do you want to use MVVM and accomplish the same?

Comment: When you control the View layer by changing it directly on ViewModel, you're breaking the architecture conceptually, but did you think about pass this CheckBoxList as a parameter of type `Layout<View>` to a "CreateCheckboxes" method?

Comment: You can setup a property in the viewmodel "int CheckBoxListCount" or a list of CheckBoxProperties if you need multiple properties for each checkbox to be created. Then in your page you react for propertychanges of this property in "OnPropertyChanged" and modify the childrens of your stacklayout based on the property

Comment: But what I not unterstand, how can I react in the page of propertychanges event. On the protected override void OnPropertyChanged the property is not showing up. And in the property set I have OnPropertyChanged(), and it's a ObservableCollection

Answer (score 0):

> I have a view (xaml) which contains a stacklayout with the id "CheckBoxList". From the viewmodel I would like to add some checkboxes to this stacklayout. But I don't know how.

Not recommended but this could be a way: You can bind the whole `StackLayout`(CheckBoxList) to a `ContentView.Content`:

1. Define the CheckBoxList in your ViewModel:

   ```
   public class MainPageViewModel
   {
       public StackLayout CheckBoxList { get; set; }
       public MainPageViewModel()
       {
           //You can modify the codes as you want
           CheckBoxList = new StackLayout();
           for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
           {
               CheckBoxList.Children.Add(new MyCheckBox { IsChecked = i % 2 == 1 ? true : false });
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your xaml use a `ContentView` and bind `CheckBoxList` to it:

   ```
   <StackLayout x:Name="root">
       <ContentView Content="{Binding CheckBoxList}"></ContentView>
   </StackLayout>
   ```
3. Binding your viewmodel in code behind:

   ```
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {

       MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
       public MainPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           ViewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
           this.BindingContext = ViewModel;
       }
   }
   ```

   Here is the complete [demo](https://github.com/elvisxia/MVVMFormsDemo)

Comment: A stacklayout in the viewmodel? This is definitely breaking the MVVM structure.

Comment: @Csharpest, So how would you solve this problem. You have in the datebase the amount of checkboxes which you have to generate, and you will load this in the view model. How would you add this dynamical checkboxes to the view?

Comment: I commented on the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382736/how-to-add-checkboxes-to-stacklayout-from-model/48394684?noredirect=1#comment83781078_48382736